# Strange PHP’s FTP wrapper behavior

Tags: php, ftp, stream

Using `fopen` on a remote FTP file results in

> failed to open stream: Failed to set up data channel: Connection refused

Filtering network trafic to FTP with Wireshark I see

```
Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Request: USER user
Response: 331 User user OK. Password required
Request: PASS password
Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Request: TYPE I
Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Request: SIZE filename
Response: 213 28344
Request: EPSV
Response: 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||25127|)
Request: RETR filename
```

Following are some DNS queries then these TCP frames:

```
60662 → 25127 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=475196536 TSecr=0 WS=128
25127 → 60662 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
45764 → 21 [FIN, ACK] Seq=102 Ack=493 Win=64128 Len=0 TSval=475196552 TSecr=2527041209
```

---

Without using the wrapper I get

```
Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Request: USER user
Response: 331 User user OK. Password required
Request: PASS password
Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Request: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (89,31,148,62,184,87)
Request: TYPE A
Response: 200 TYPE is now ASCII
Request: RETR filename
Response: 150-Accepted data connection
Response: 226-File successfully transferred
Response: 226 Logout.
```

Seems like an issue with EPSV then?

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). FTP URL wrapper uses the passive mode. If the wrapper connection does not work for you, the problem is likely different than you think. – What exact error do you get?

Comment: I get `failed to open stream: Failed to set up data channel: Connection refused`. Other thing I suspected was the password escaping as it contains an exclamation mark. But I tried countless combinations and none worked.

Comment: Do you have an access to server-side logs? Or can you do a protocol capture of the connection? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: No access to server logs. I never did any protocol capture but I can try. Using PHP 7.1.33

Comment: @MartinPrikryl after launching Wireshark it appears you were right. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you add full a capture without the wrapper?

Comment: Is the `89.31.148.62` the IP address of your FTP server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211122/discussion-between-matthecat-and-martin-prikryl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo I guess my issue is the same as https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69580

PHP’s FTP wrapper uses EPSV, while `ftp_pasv` uses PASV with IPv4. The server I try to download from has an issue with EPSV and the wrapper won’t fallback to PASV, hence the error.

One could ask the server’s administrator to fix their setup but in my case that just means I won’t be able to use the wrapper.